# Why does the two OH bonds in H2O have different bond disassociation enthalpies? How does the bond cleavage happen here?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure, molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals

I came across this question, and in the text it was written as 'change in the chemical environment'. I wasn't satisfied with this explanation, so I am looking for a more detailed answer on this matter but didnt find much about it/

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: Neither books nor magazine articles nor SE questions should try to put near all the story to their titles.

With comparable lengths of the question title and the question body, the former is too long and/or the latter too short.

Answer (score 1):

Two $\ce{OH}$ bonds in **any** molecule have different dissociation enthalpies, as only the first one is related to the original molecule.

The second one is related to the original molecule with the cleaved first $\ce{OH}$ bond.

If both bonds have the same chemical neighborhood and are far enough from each other, then their dissociation enthalpies converge to each other with the growing distance.